# Decay curve best fit SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, best-fit-curve

I am having a problem when I try to find best fit to my data. Using **scipy.optimize.curve_fit** to create best fit. My data and code is:

**EDIT** You can download the data file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6c0e-DwluM5RmJFemgyT3NkeTg/view?usp=sharing).
data is,

```
         a             b            b2
55478   1.07E+43    54395.93833 
56333   1.63E+43    54380.01385 
57540   2.57E+43    52393.31605 
61866   7.32E+43    52212.22838 52212.22838
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from __future__ import division

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fit
import glob
import os
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.patches as patches

pf = pd.read_csv('/home/imhotep/Desktop/lala.csv', sep=',', encoding ='utf-8')



a1= pf['a'].max()
b1 = pf['b2'].max()
npoc=100

x = np.linspace((b1), (pf['b'].max()),npoc)
yy = np.linspace((pf['a'].min()), (pf['a'].max()), npoc)


fig = plt.figure()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)

def h(x,k):
    return a1* (((x-(b1))/(k))**(-(5./3.)))


popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,x,yy)

print 'POPT,', popt,'PCOV',pcov
y_fi1 = h(x, *popt)

ax4.plot(x, y_fi1, label='fit', ls='-', color='blue')

ax4.plot(pf['b'], pf['a'], ls='None', color='blue', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

like that. When I run the code I'm getting that fit:
[image: fit]

But, it should be roughly like that:

[image: fitted]

Can anyone tell me where I go wrong? I am beginner about curve fitting.

Comment: Your numbers are huge, which makes this whole ordeal (and possibly even the plotting) inaccurate. While it won't be exactly equivalent to what you're doing now, but you should try plotting the logarithm of your model to the logarithm of your y data, and using those parameters if they are better.

Comment: You fit the curve to some weird linear interpolations (`x`, `yy`) between some of the points. You want to fit to the actual points (see answer from @snow), and then use the interpolated `x` only for plotting the curve (`y_fi1 = h(x, *popt)` seems correct).

Comment: I think @kazemakase is right. When you call *curve_fit* you need to pass it the function that it is to fit (which is what you have done) with the vector of 'x' values and then the vector of 'y' values.

Comment: So, you think I don't have to create noisy data?

Comment: No. Data are usually noisy enough. :)

Comment: @anniejcannon Have you tried to use `popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,pf['b'], pf['a'])`?

Comment: We know what one of the variables is; it's luminosity. What's the other one?

Comment: Other one is time, on MJD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to fit a model to your 4 blue points described by a and b?

You should be doing fit in this direction then:

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,b,a)
```

**EDIT:**

as mentioned in the comments of the question and this answer, you should be using the fit function only on your original data and then the newly created array using `np.linspace` to show the fit.

Here is what I got from your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

pf = pd.read_csv('lala.csv', sep=',', encoding ='utf-8')

a1 = pf['a'].max()
#b1 = pf['b2'].max()

x = pf["b"]
y = pf["a"]

def h(x,k,b1):
    return a1*((x-b1)/k)**(-5/3)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,x,y)

print 'POPT,', popt,'PCOV',pcov

xfit = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),100)
y_fi1 = h(xfit, *popt)

fig = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax4.plot(xfit, y_fi1, label='fit', ls='-', color='blue')
ax4.plot(x, y, ls='None', color='blue', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Using the `curve_fit` to find only parameter `k` resulted in an error, therefore I included b1 as a search parameter. Then it does find a fit, however still not completelly satisfying.
The output:

```
POPT, [   238.09666313  51973.04601693] 
PCOV [[ 21500.32886377 -22370.88448044] [-22370.88448044  23850.34961769]]
```

Comment: How is this helpful when the question contains `popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,x,yy)`?

Comment: It is helpful because `x` and `yy` are not the data points. The answer is just missing some form of explanation :)

Comment: @kazemakase thanks, I think I see what you mean. Still, the answer in its current form is only confusing.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I agree. Just noticed that a and b are not even declared in the question.

Comment: x and    yy are fake data points for model. How can I get that decay curve without them? It not worked. :(

Comment: Looks okay but, it passing the last data point. It has to be take last point too.

Comment: the `curve_fit` function uses all the points from your file. `x = pf["b"]` and
`y = pf["a"]` represent whole columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might try obtaining a better initial estimate of `k` by first linearising your equation in the old-fashioned way ...

[image: Linearised form]

... and then calculating a simple linear regression using the software of your choice. Here I used **statsmodels** to get 0.0007 for 1/k, implying an initial estimate of about 1400 for use with **curve_fit**.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('lala.csv')
time_min = min(df.time)
luminosity_max = max(df.luminosity)
df['Y'] = (df.luminosity/luminosity_max)**(-0.6)
results = smf.ols('Y ~ time', data=df).fit()
print (results.summary())
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = sm.graphics.plot_fit(results, 1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

From the error bars in the plot produced by this code it's obvious (if it wasn't otherwise) that there's considerable uncertainty in this estimate of k.

[image: linearised regression plot]

I still haven't succeeded in making curve_fit work. However, you might be interested in this modification to the function to be optimised. After renaming the columns in your csv (so the variables would be less confusing for me) I rewrote the main code in this way. I found that values for *h* around 1400 gave *nan* for the first time. I decided to simply replace these *nan*'s with the maximum luminosity. If you run this I think you'll find that *k=700* gives the best (crude) fit to start with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

df = pd.read_csv('lala.csv')
print (df)

luminosities = df.luminosity
times = df.time

luminosity_max= max(luminosities)
time_min = min(times)

def h(time,k):
    result = luminosity_max*((time-time_min)/k)**(-5./3.)
    if np.isnan(result):
        result = luminosity_max
    return result

for time in range(52000,56000,1000):
    print (time, h(time,2800), h(time,1400),h(time,700))

#~ popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,times,luminosities,700)
#~ print ('POPT,', popt,'PCOV',pcov)
```

Comment: When I run the code I couldn't get k value. Also, fit that you did is not curve. :/

Comment: As I indicated at the outset, my emphasis was on trying to obtain a better initial estimate for *k* and my suggested approach was to *linearise* the given function. Linear functions aren't curved. Notice that the linearised function involves the *inverse* of *k*. **statsmodels** provides a LS estimate of *1/k** of 0.0007. Which implies that 1400 *might* be a reasonable starting value for use in fitting a curve to the original function that you had. However, given the results in my second answer, I doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong with curve_fit. I suspect that the mathematical model is a very poor fit for those data. Here's why. I ran the following code to calculate least-square error for various values of *k*.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('lala.csv')
print (df)

luminosities = df.luminosity
times = df.time

luminosity_max= max(luminosities)
time_min = min(times)

def h(time,k):
    result = luminosity_max*(max(time-time_min,5)/k)**(-5./3.)
    if np.isnan(result):
        result = luminosity_max
    return result

def LS(k):
    return sum([(luminosity-h(time,k))**2 for (luminosity,time) in zip(luminosities,times)])

for k in range(10,110,10):
    print (k, LS(k))
```

Results:

```
   dummy1  luminosity          time       dummy2
0   55478    1.066349  54395.938333          NaN
1   56333    1.630938  54380.013854          NaN
2   57540    2.569603  52393.316048          NaN
3   61866    7.324060  52212.228380  52212.22838
10 263.810260704
20 4431.42454446
30 18991.1298817
40 51557.4862318
50 110648.507655
60 205525.705606
70 346090.508811
80 542810.685895
90 806664.876933
100 1149099.00104
```

What I notice is that the smaller the value of *k* the smaller the LSE. But I think this would make the fitted model 'hug' the horizontal axis, as you saw.